# Converting a long to bytes for efficient transmission

Tags: c#, byte, long-integer

I'm creating a serialisation format, and part of the header is the length of the body.

To do this, I'm allocating a fixed number of bytes (currently 4) which I want to use to store as long a number as possible.

As a result I want to store a `long` in a `byte[]` (I guess this could be called base 256?).

Here is my code:

```
long val = 25484394;
var encoded = new byte[4];

var max = 0L;

for (var i = 0; i < encoded.Length; ++i)
{
    max += (long)Math.Pow((int)byte.MaxValue, i);
}

if (val >= max)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", $"{val} is too large to be encoded (max value is {max})");
    
    for (var i = encoded.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
//This line is wrong
        encoded[i] = (byte)(int)Math.Floor(val / Math.Pow(byte.MaxValue, i));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you trying to accomplish... but normally all those conversions are done by BitConverter (I linked duplicate that shows it)... Limiting size of sections in a file format to int.MaxValue is generally bad idea - clarifying why you decided to do that would be helpful. If you believe the duplicate is unrelated - please [edit] the question so everyone can understand why standard approach is not suitable to this question and what exactly is different.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `BitConverter` doesn't allow you to specify the size of byte array used for the encoded, the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a `long` value to a byte array (i.e., base 256), you'll need to use bitwise operations. Let's break it down step by step.

**Ensure you're not going over the limit:**
A 4-byte (32-bit) space can represent values from `0` to `2^32 - 1`. So, `max` should be `2^32 - 1` (which is `4294967295`), not the sum you calculated using `byte.MaxValue`.

**Converting the long to bytes:**
To obtain the bytes that make up a `long`, you can perform bit masking and shifting. For each byte you want to extract:

- Use bitwise AND (`&`) with a mask of `0xFF` to obtain the least significant 8 bits of the value.
- Store the result in your byte array.
- Right-shift the original value by 8 bits to move on to the next byte.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```cs
long val = 25484394;
var encoded = new byte[4];

// A 4-byte (32-bit) space can represent values from 0 to 2^32 - 1.
long max = (1L << 32) - 1;

if (val > max)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", $"{val} is too large to be encoded (max value is {max})");

for (var i = 0; i < encoded.Length; i++)
{
    encoded[encoded.Length - 1 - i] = (byte)(val & 0xFF);
    val >>= 8; // Right shift the value by 8 bits
}
```

**Here's what's happening:**

- The mask `0xFF` will get the least significant 8 bits of `val`.
- After we've taken these bits and stored them, we shift `val` right by 8 bits so the next 8 bits will be in the least significant position for the next iteration. This process continues until we've filled the entire `encoded` array.

**Note:** It's important to handle situations where `val` is negative or beyond the range of the byte array. The code above assumes `val` is always non-negative and you're doing a check for the maximum allowable value. If there's a chance `val` can be negative, you'll need to add another check for that.

Comment: chatGPT is banned at SO